# SharePoint throws "Value cannot be null" after successful authentication via custom STS

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth

We have custom WS-Fedaration based STS implemented (WIF 4.5) that has worked fine for several years. The STS returns user to SharePoint 2016 like it should, including the identity claim that has been configured in SharePoint (emailaddress in our case), and few other claims.

However, I cannot figure out why the SharePoint at  `https://sharepoint.mycompany.com/_trust/default.aspx` has at some point started to throw *Value cannot be null* error.

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.FormatAccountName(String provider, String user) +43042497
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous) +4241
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest() +264
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest() +283
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Request() +29
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.EnsureSPWebRequest(SPWeb web) +236
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext context) +818
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.RedirectValidateInternal(String url, SPWeb web, HttpContext context, Boolean isTrusted) +344
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.DetermineRedirectUrl(String urlProposed, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, SPWeb overrideWeb, String queryString, String& urlRedirect) +1118
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.Redirect(String url, SPRedirectFlags flags, HttpContext context, String queryString) +77
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnSignedIn(EventArgs eventArgs) +702
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request) +736
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +323
   Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +206
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +75
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +93
```

I've even disassembled the SharePoint assemblies, and it would point that the `currentUserIdentity.Name` is empty or null. I cannot understand why, as the `wresult` being passed to SharePoint contains the `emailaddress` claim:

```
<saml:Attribute AttributeName="emailaddress" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims"><saml:AttributeValue>xyz@mycompany.com</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute>
```

And the `emailaddress` is the identity claim of the registered STS in SharePoint

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $t = Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Identity "STS-Test"
$t.IdentityClaimTypeInformation


DisplayName                    : EmailAddress
InputClaimType                 : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
MappedClaimType                : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
IsIdentityClaim                : True
AcceptOnlyKnownClaimValues     : False
ClaimValueModificationAction   : None
ClaimValueModificationArgument : 
KnownClaimValues               : {}
UpgradedPersistedProperties    :
```

I have been able to reproduce the same issue on DEV environment. I suspect some Windows/SharePoint patch or WIndows Update patch has changed something as there hasn't been any code updates to STS and STS itself would seem to work fine.

The ULS logs show the same error (nothing of help even with VerboseEx log level), and only row that catches my eye is the

```
Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=5
```

that would perhaps indicate the same issue that the username is not properly parsed from the STS return message. But I cannot now confirm whether that was populated here earlier when it worked when logging in via Custom STS.

All ideas how to proceed with troubleshooting are very welcome, thank you!